Digital multimeter UT61C on CrossOver
Has anyone ever tried to run the UT61C, D, or E multimeter in CrossOver? The program included with the meter starts up nicely, but unfortunately, there is no connection between the meter and the program. I tried linking USB ports to COM, but nothing helped. The 'lsusb' command gives:
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 1a86:e008 QinHeng Electronics HID-based serial adapater

The device appears as /dev/hidraw1 and /dev/usb/hiddev1. Unfortunately, linking to com1 doesn't help. If it appeared as 'ttyUSB0', for example, I might be able to do something with it, but not in this case.
